# Disable horizontal vertical scrolling iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, overflow

I am in the process of making a web app and would like to disable horizontal overflow (elastic band) type scrolling.

I have tried everything I can think of and find on here including the following:

`html, body {width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden;}`

But nothing seems to be working...

The url I am wanting this to work on is this:
http://winn-brown.co.uk/shmee-feed/index.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add overflows to your body as bellow.

```
body {
        overflow: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Let me know if this works for you!

You might want to consider using a viewport tag in your HTML.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Comment: Behaves in the same way unfortunately.

Comment: Hello @dwinnbrown. I edited my answer, hopes for the best !

Comment: am already using this one: `<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />`